# Not able to display the div content in two container

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display the randomly displayed values from 'test1' and 'test2' arrays into two different containers "mainone" and "maintwo". Now I am able to get the random values from array but failed to display the whole html content in containers during on click of `click me` button each time;

My fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/yecoqusp/

[Page with data on load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7NK4.png)

```
var teama = ["one_1", "one_2", "one_3","one_4", "one_5"];
var test1 = [];
var test2 = [];
function startTeam(){
    for(var i = teama.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        var randomIndex =Math.floor(Math.random()*teama.length);
        var rand = teama[randomIndex];
        teama.splice(randomIndex, 1);
        if(i%2){
            test1.push(rand);
        }else{
            test2.push(rand);
        }
    }
    alert(test1);
    alert(test2);

    for(var j=0; j<test1.length; j++){
        $('#mainone').html('<div id="' + test1[j] + '" class="well">' + test1[j] + '</div>');
    }

    for(var k=0; k<test2.length; k++){
        $('#maintwo').html('<div id="' + test2[k] + '" <div class="well"></div>' + test2[k] + '</div>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure jquery is available and your function resides in global scope ? [To me it looks like its working](https://jsfiddle.net/yecoqusp/1/)

Comment: It looks like maintwo has an issue in the html that is being set.. you open the div, supply the id, then open a new div without closing the other one. `'<div id="' + test2[k] + '" <div class="well"></div>'` <--- there.

Comment: So, I noticed you don't have jquery in that fiddle, and you were not loading your js properly. This works: https://jsfiddle.net/jvincilione/yecoqusp/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to work on your fiddle, but no avail, as a guesswork, you have this

```
for(var j=0; j<test1.length; j++){
    $('#mainone').html('<div id="' + test1[j] + '" class="well">' + test1[j] + '</div>');
}
for(var k=0; k<test2.length; k++){
    $('#maintwo').html('<div id="' + test2[k] + '" <div class="well"></div>' + test2[k] + '</div>');
}
```

each loop in the two for-loops is overriding the corresponding div's html,
 instead create two variables, say `main1html` and `main2html` outside the for loops and the for-loops should be something like:

```
for(var j=0; j<test1.length; j++){
    main1html += '<div id="' + test1[j] + '" class="well">' + test1[j] + '</div>');
}
for(var k=0; k<test2.length; k++){
    main2html += '<div id="' + test2[k] + '" <div class="well"></div>' + test2[k] + '</div>';
}
```

and after the two for-loops assign the final html to both divs, like this:

```
$('#mainone').html(main1html);
$('#maintwo').html(main2html);
```

Comment: @soccerway, because I couldn't work on your fiddle, I provided this answer, if this didn't fix your problem tell me to delete it

Comment: Thanks Mi-Creativity..i have tried your code as well, its not working yet, i am getting the test1 and test2 alert with random div id's ..but not displaying the random divs in those container during on click

Comment: @soccerway, check this out http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/GomemM?editors=001, is this what you're after?

Comment: Almost there :), that's what i am looking for, but right now the div's content, image, child div's under are not displaying properly

Comment: Ok got it, again the `.html()` is overriding the content of the two divs, check this http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/GomemM?editors=001 ??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, as was mentioned elsewhere, using .html() is just overriding the data each time. There are a couple issues in your code, however.

1. You are not properly closing your div(s) in the second loop.
2. You need to append the new data to the container (clear the container first if you need to, I do in my example.)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jvincilione/yecoqusp/4/)

```
var teama = ["one_1", "one_2", "one_3","one_4", "one_5"];
var test1 = [];
var test2 = [];
function startTeam(){
    for(var i = teama.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    var randomIndex =Math.floor(Math.random()*teama.length);
    var rand = teama[randomIndex];
    teama.splice(randomIndex, 1);
    if(i%2){
     test1.push(rand);
    }else{
     test2.push(rand);
    }
  }
  alert(test1);
  alert(test2);
  // i'm emptying the containers, you may not need to depending
  // on your implementation
  $('#mainone').empty();
  $('#maintwo').empty();
  for(var j=0; j < test1.length; j++){
      // use append here, not html
      $('#mainone').append('<div id="' + test1[j] + '" class="well">' + test1[j] + '</div>');
  }

  for(var k=0; k<test2.length; k++){
      // use append here, not html
      // i also fix your markup ( you were not closing the div properly)
      $('#maintwo').append('<div id="' + test2[k] + '" class="well">' + test2[k] + '</div>');
  }

}
```

Comment: @ Jacques, you are right. Now its displaying the div ids randomly, but after appending the problem i have lost div content like ( img), header, all other properties like draggable, droppable, and other inner div ids ...code as below

Comment: $('#maintwo').empty();
  
  for(var k=0; k < test2.length; k++){   
   $('#maintwo').append('<div id="' + test2[k]+'"><div class="well"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/"><div id="><label for="lastname"></label></div><div id=""><textarea rows="3" cols="26"></textarea><br><br><button type="button" class="">Save</button></div></div></div>');
   
  }

Comment: So, if you read the commented lines in my code sample, I state that you may not need to empty your containers. Try taking out the `$('#maintwo').empty()` and see if that does the trick.

Comment: @Jacques..It didn't help much

Comment: Does the js fiddle work properly, and what doesn't work?